# for loop, append data

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a variable x of size x=(8000,2).
I want to select the value at each 100 location, so, (0,99,198,297...), and apply a second loop which multiplies that value 100 times, and save it in a list, thus at the end of the 2 loops, I have a variable of size (8000,2)

A functional code is:

```
num_data = 8000

x_data = []
x_data.append(np.random.uniform(high=-1, low=1,size=(num_data, 2)))
x_data=np.asarray(x_data)



K= np.random.uniform(high=-1, low=1, size=(2, 2))

ys=[Obs_x0]

for i in range (80):
    Obs_x0 = x_data[:,i*99]
   
    traj=[Obs_x0]
    for j in range(99):
        Obs_x0 = np.matmul(Obs_x0, K)    
        traj.append(Obs_x0)
        
        ys.append(traj)
        
ys=np.asarray(ys)
print(ys.shape)
```

When I run it, the shape of  `ys(7921,)` when it should be  `ys(8000,2)`. I think that the problem is that the code is not appending  Obs_x0 from the first loop

Any ides how to solve it>

Comment: I suggest you learn about broadcasting. This is a technique from numpy that does the looping for you.

Comment: Also note that `ys=[Obs_x0]` makes a list with a reference to whatever `Obs_x0` is referring to. It DOES NOT copy `Obs_x0`.

Comment: Your code is not functional as written because `Obs_x0` is not defined before the loop executes.

Comment: thanks for your comments, so, how I copy ``` Obs_x0``` . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave `ys` empty before the for loop -> `ys=[]`.

the range in your second loop is faulty: `range(99)` counts from `0-98`.
what you want is probably `range(100`) which counts from `0-99`.

your final code should look like this:

```
import numpy as np

num_data = 8000

x_data = []
x_data.append(np.random.uniform(high=-1, low=1, size=(num_data, 2)))
x_data = np.asarray(x_data)
print(x_data.shape)
K = np.random.uniform(high=-1, low=1, size=(2, 2))

ys = []

for i in range(80):
    Obs_x0 = x_data[:, i * 99]

    traj = [Obs_x0]
    for j in range(100):
        Obs_x0 = np.matmul(Obs_x0, K)
        ys.append(Obs_x0)

ys = np.asarray(ys)
print(ys.shape)
```

Comment: thanks tetris programming. One question, the final shape of ys is: (8000, 101, 1, 2) instead of (8000, 2). why's would it be the case?

Comment: hi Carlos, probably because you use traj = [Obs_x0] and traj.append(Obs_x0) and then append the entire traj thing to your ys.
Maybe just adding the Obs_x0 value to ys is closed what u need.
Check the edited code above